# CSS transform not working in css transition?

Tags: css, transform, transition

I really hope I'm missing something simple here, because this is driving me crazy.

I'd like the element to rotateZ(360deg) when the class is applied, then back when the class is removed. For some reason, none of the transitions are happening. Any ideas?

**CSS**

```
#img-cover {
    content: url(../img/menu-center-plus.svg);
    border-radius: 66px;
    position:absolute;
    left:95px;
    top:95px;
    z-index: 1500;
    display:block;
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow 0.5s, opacity 1.2s, -webkit-transform 1s;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px rgba(55, 55, 55, 0.6);
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-360deg);
    opacity: 0;
}

.twirlIn {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s, -webkit-transform 1s;
    opacity: 1!important;
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(360deg);
}
```

Comment: can you fiddle your post.! [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: @Vivek Vikranth It looks a bit gross out of context, but here it is:
[http://jsfiddle.net/5Knku/1](jsFiddle)
Click on the cat in the top left, then click on the red cat to bring it back down. The bacon is the one that should spin.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of an odd one but if you change the CSS to

```
#img-cover.twirlIn { ...
```

it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are overwriting the transition in `#img-cover {}`. Also, since the class gets removed when you animate it the second time, the transform transition gets removed too (in this case it doesn't matter though since it's being overwritten).

Add the transition to your `#img-cover` as such should fix the problem.

```
#img-cover{
   -webkit-transition: box-shadow 0.5s, opacity 2s, -webkit-transform 1s;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Knku/3/)